# I want to create trigger but I dont know how to do that. Below is the sample

Tags: sql, oracle, database-trigger

I want to create trigger but I don't know how to do that. Below is the sample:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER checkDuration
   after UPDATE on comm_shipping
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   quantity NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM comm_orders c
      WHERE C.ORDER_ID = :new.order_id 
      AND c.quantity = 1;
   IF quantity=NULL THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR('no more items');
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      NULL;
END;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take your time to improve your question: properly format the code, clearly describe what you want you have tried so far and where you're stuck, add error message if you experienced them etc. The [Question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) can be helpful.

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Where should the value of `quantity` in the `IF` statement come from?

Comment: Hi, Nikhil. Have you tried to run your code? What happened? What error messages were produced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following ( I suppose your DBMS is `Oracle` or `DB2` because of `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` ):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER checkDuration
AFTER UPDATE ON comm_shipping
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   quantity NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT c.quantity
     INTO quantity   -- this part is missing
     FROM comm_orders c
    WHERE c.order_id = :new.order_id;

    IF quantity is NULL THEN 
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'no more items'); -- you need a code 
                                                        -- between -20000 and -20999
    END IF;
   EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
END;
```

Comment: I compiled the code but I do not know how to execute the code. Can you please help?

Comment: @NikhilSalaria whenever you update `comm_shipping` table, the trigger gets activated.